# Running new command only if it exists

Tags: compiling, conditionals

How do I get LaTeX to run a command only if it exists?
I need something like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \newcommand{\mytitle}{Title Test}
\begin{document}
\if mytitle exists
\mytitle %true
\else
do not run the command
\fi
\end{document}
```

To prevent the error message appears: 'Undefined control sequence \mytitle'
I need to decide this because I will use Boolean operation on multiple files.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I usually use `\ifdefined`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\newcommand{\mytitle}{ducks}
\begin{document}

\ifdefined\mytitle
Yay, \mytitle!
\else
Oops.
\fi
\end{document}
```

As Martin Scharrer mentioned in the comment, `\ifdefined` is part of the e-TeX extension.

Comment: Note that `\ifdefined` is part of the e-TeX extension, which is part of any modern LaTeX compiler.

Comment: Thanks @Martin, I'll add that to my answer. `=)`

Comment: Thank you Paulo Cereda. Andrey Vihrov i dont undestand you.

Comment: @Regis: Please add all comments to the appropriate answers, i.e. add you comment to Andrey below his answer.

Answer (score 19):

There is the kernel command `\@ifundefined`:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{mytitle}{do not run the command}{\mytitle}
\makeatother
```

Otherwise, as already mentioned

```
\ifdefined\mytitle
  \mytitle
\else
  do not run the command
\fi
```

The two will give different result in case

```
\let\mytitle\relax
```

has been given before the test, because `\@ifundefined` tests whether the control sequence name given as argument is equivalent to `\relax`. There are TeXnical reasons for this.

Comment: Very useful explanation of the difference between `\ifdefined` and (negative of) `\@ifundefined`!

Answer (score 15):

An alternative way is to use `\providecommand` to define a command that does nothing. This will only define the command if it is not already defined.  If it is already defined, the original definition is not altered. This eliminates the need to test it every time you want to use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\providecommand{\mytitle}{}%

This does nothing: \mytitle
\end{document}
```

If the command is expected to take a parameter you can do something like:

```
\providecommand{\mytitle}[1]{#1}%
```

which will just return the parameter, and hence do nothing with it.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\csname … \endcsname` for that. `\csname … \endcsname` constructs a control sequence with the given name. If the control sequence does not exist, it is temporarily let equal to `\relax`, which does nothing.

So,

```
\csname mytitle\endcsname
```

will work both when `\mytitle` is and is not defined.

If your command takes parameters, this simple method can't be used anymore. Then you can use the `\@ifundefined` command:

```
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{mytitle}{not defined}{defined}
\makeatother
```