# Merging \newcommand and \renewcommand

Tags: macros

Is there a merged command `\maybenewcommand` that is either `\newcommand` or `\renewcommand`, depending on the situation: if the command is not yet defined, use `\newcommand` and use `\renewcommand` otherwise.

I currently merge multiple papers into a large document. I use the same commands in several of them, with slightly different meaning. I would now like to avoid to check for each `\newcommand` if it has been used in earlier places and then replacing them by `\renewcommand` by hand.

Thanks, Christian

Comment: Are you looking for `\providecommand` or the combinations `\providecommand\foo{}\renewcommand\foo...` (which will always create a definition)?

Comment: Maybe the answer is here : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/running-new-command-only-if-it-exists

Comment: I wasn't aware of \providecommand. It's not quite what I want since I want to possibly update the behaviour. But adding a new command consisting of \providecommand\foo{} and \renewcommand\foo{...} should do the job.

Comment: An analogous construction should be working using \ifdefined. Thanks to both of you for the pointers!

Comment: @ChristianStump So just to clarify: you want a macro that overrides an existing value for that macro if there is one and declare a new value if there is no such existing value? Read: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-def I'd go with `\let`

Answer (score 10):

There are the TeX and the LaTeX version:

TeX:

```
\def\mycommand#1{...}% overwrites without any warning if  \mycommand exists
```

LaTeX:

```
 \newcommand\mycommand[1]{...}%  gives an error message if exists
 \renewcommand\mycommand[1]{...}%  gives an error message if not exists

 \providecommand\mycommand{}  
 \renewcommand\mycommand[1]{...}%  overwrites or defines command
```